# Android Studio, emulator using webcam has landscape orientation instead of portrait

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera, emulation, android-virtual-device

I'm currently trying to test an application through a Pixel 4 AVD in Android Studio.  Switching the camera in my emulator to use my webcam worked, as I can see an image, but for some reason it is depicting my webcam image in landscape mode, even though the camera in the emulator is in portrait mode.  Any help with fixing this would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add another device in AVD manager and remove this one.